# Include CORS Headers in WSO2 APIM 4.0.0 Token API Response

Tags: cors, wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server

Good morning everybody.

I am working witn WSO2 APIM 4.0.0 using WSO2 IS 5.11.0 as Key Manager, when a WSO2 APIM hosted api is called from frontend application, the following error appears in developer's console on the web browser:

```
 Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://apim.mydomain/oauth2/token' from origin 'https://frontendapp.mydomain' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

Making a token request from Postman to `https://apim.mydomain/oauth2/token` (WSO2 APIM token API), effectively the Access-Control-Allow-Origin is missing in the response. Some blogs and wso2 documentation recomended to include  CORSRequestHandler handler to token API, I did this in this way:

- Configuring WSO2 APIM to use Artifact configuration files adding the following lines to  the deployment.toml file:

```
[apim.sync_runtime_artifacts.gateway.skip_list]
apis = ["_OpenService_.xml","_RevokeAPI_.xml", "_TokenAPI_.xml"]
```

- Including the `_TokenApi_.xml` file to wso2am-4.0.0/repository/deployment/server/synapse-configs/default/api path with the following code:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><api xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="_WSO2AMTokenAPI_" context="/oauth2/token" binds-to="default">
        <resource methods="POST" binds-to="default" url-mapping="/*" faultSequence="_token_fault_">
            <inSequence>
                <property name="uri.var.portnum" expression="get-property('keyManager.port')"/>
                <property name="uri.var.hostname" expression="get-property('keyManager.hostname')"/>
                <send>
                    <endpoint>
                        <http uri-template="https://{uri.var.hostname}:{uri.var.portnum}/oauth2/token">
                            <timeout>
                                <duration>60000</duration>
                                <responseAction>fault</responseAction>
                            </timeout>
                        </http>
                    </endpoint>
                </send>
            </inSequence>
            <outSequence>
                <send/>
            </outSequence>
        </resource>
        <handlers>
            <handler class="org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.ext.APIManagerCacheExtensionHandler"/>
            <handler class="org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.common.SynapsePropertiesHandler"/>
            <handler class="org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.security.CORSRequestHandler">
                <property name="apiImplementationType" value="ENDPOINT"/>
                <property name="allowHeaders" value="authorization,Access-Control-Allow-Origin,Content-Type"/>
                <property name="allowedOrigins" value="*"/>
                <property name="allowedMethods" value="GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS"/>
            </handler>
        </handlers>
    </api>
```

- Configuring WSO2 IS to enable CORS including the following configuration into deployent.toml file

```
    [cors]
    allow_generic_http_requests = true
    allow_any_origin = true
    allowed_origins = []
    allow_subdomains = false
    supported_methods = [
        "GET",
        "POST",
        "HEAD",
        "OPTIONS"
    ]
    support_any_header = true
    supported_headers = []
    exposed_headers = ["Location","authorization","Access-Control-Allow-Origin","Content-Type"]
    supports_credentials = true
    max_age = 3600
    tag_requests = false
```

But it is still without working, the response from WSO2 APIM token API do not include the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header

Any clue about how I can enable CORSRequestHandler handler in the new WSO2 token API and include the required Access-Control-Allow-Origin header?

Best regards and thaks

References:
https://github.com/wso2/product-apim/issues/7230
https://medium.com/@suhanr/enable-cors-for-token-api-in-wso2-api-manger-so-that-your-react-app-can-generate-renew-8b45f246a3f2

Answer (score 1):

In API Manager, you can enable CORS per API or as a global configuration that is applied across all APIs. But the token api /token are not covered from this configuration since the CORS configurations are valid for the APIs created using the API Publisher application.

From the WSO2 API Manager 4.0.0 version onwards the token related endpoints are not proxied hence we can use the following configuration to add CORS for token endpoint.

1. Stop the server.
2. Go to the <APIM_HOME>repository/deployment/server/webapps directory.
3. Open the web.xml file inside the oauth2.war/WEB-INF directory. (You need to edit the web.xml file inside the WAR file)
4. Then add the below content into the file.

```html
<filter>
  <filter-name>CORS</filter-name>
  <filter-class>com.thetransactioncompany.cors.CORSFilter</filter-class>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>cors.allowOrigin</param-name>
    <param-value>*</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>cors.supportedMethods</param-name>
    <param-value>GET, POST, HEAD, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS</param-value>
  </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>CORS</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

5. Save the file.
6. Take back up of the oauth2 directory and delete it in the webapps directory.
7. Then start the server, this will redeploy the oauth2.war directory content with the CORS filter changes and you will be able to see the CORS changes when invoking the oauth2 /token endpoint.

Answer (score -1):

Ideally CORS “Access-Control-Allow-Origin: xyz “l header needs to be done at your application which initiates the API requests. So can you add headers having domain names of API manager and IS on your main page calling APIs via your JavaScripts.

Also host names without the tld (e.g. mydomain) behave weird , so could you try with something like “mydomain.com” or something along.

Please refer to the article at [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS).

e.g.
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *.mydomain.com